# Imported account not visible in Mist

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I used jaxx to create my etherium account, but after reading some comments, I decided to stop using it and switch to Mist 0.9.0.

I got my private key and used geth import account command. Import was successful but my account is not visible in Mist GUI.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Hi there - did you solve this problem in the end?

Comment: No. I just switched to Parity. Mist was not worth my time, unstable and too many bugs.